# How to convert VAD(Valence-Arousal-Dominance) tags to Ekman's basic emotions?

Tags: converters, emotion

I am currently developing a music emotion recognition project. I have a song dataset with their VAD emotion tags. Is there a way to convert these VAD tags to Ekman's basic emotions or any emotion model? My dataset looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15CkO.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ekman started with 7 basic emotions and later converted them into 6 basic emotions: fear, anger, joy, sadness, disgust, and surprise. Recently I was reading a review paper over basic emotions model and dimensional model which can be found [here](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2019.00781/full). In it's figure 1 they have mapped all the basic emotions over a 2 dimensional plane of Valence and Arousal. Similarly [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-VAD-Valence-Arousal-Dominance-model-spanned-across-the-six-basic-emotions_fig1_338118399) they have mapped the same basic emotions over the 3 dimensional plane of VAD, so what you can do is that you now have the coordinates of basic emotions over the 3D plane, using that you can project other points of your database over these points by doing some simple maths I believe.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I used Russell's 2D Emotion Circumplex with different dataset including valance-arousal values and created 4 basic emotion labels.